# How do I know whether my laptop's fan is working?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

I am using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), and my CPU is running at 70-90°C. I think my fan is probably not working. How can I check that?

Comment: open the case, look.... or listen.

Comment: The fact Speccy is reporting temperatures in the 70s means your fan is working.  If it wasn't it would be 90+

Comment: @Ramhound you can't explicitly tell that without know the laptop and CPU models...

Comment: @JeremyPare - A fan can be operational but be inefficient.  I don't need to know anything about the laptop to determine that a CPU running at 70 and 90 degrees celsius is more or less average when dealing with mobile procssors.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but always make sure that wherever the exhaust comes from in your laptop is not blocked.  Early laptops, ironically, had their fans exhaust down out of the bottom, and were literally blocked by laps - apparently meant for tables.  The vents might also be covered in lint, also reducing the exhaust effect.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not rare to see some laptop CPU running a 35-40°C at idle with their CPU fan working at almost no RPMs. So what tells you that a mobile CPU couldn't be running at 70-90°C with a bad fan?

Comment: @JeremyPare - Because a CPU without a working heatsink fan is going to shut down within seconds.

Comment: @Ramhound not true at all. there is even laptops with passive cooling system (fanless). Read this: https://www.quora.com/How-good-is-passive-cooling-system-on-laptops

Comment: I've generally found that by the time your laptop actually starts turning the fan up, its already too late to cool it to the point where its not a paperweight. They usually optimize to the Quite over the Cool.  I always hated that most manufacturers don't allow you to configure power management, to be a bit more aggressive.

Comment: @JeremyPare - Quora is on my lifetime list of websites (and I will never visit it again), even if I am offered, 10 trillion dollars to visit that particular waste of bits

Comment: @Ramhound I just took the first result of my Google search. You can do your own if you want though.

Comment: I am more than familiar with this subject.  However, I think we have exceeded the usefulness, of this discussion at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot hear the fan and cannot feel it's air moving, then it may not be able to turn.

I have seen a laptop with such dust contamination that the fan could not spin. The laptop would boot and run for around 5 minutes before crashing.

Applying some compressed air to fan produced a large cloud of dust and freed the fan to spin normally. When in doubt, clean it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) to see the speed of your fan. However, not all fan are reporting speed to the system.